# Is Supremum of sequence of bounded random variables a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I was thinking about the following situation :

Suppose we have ${\{X_n\}}$ is a sequence of bounded random variables . Is it true that $\mathbb{lim \  sup} X_n$ is also a random variable ?

( I get a feeling that the answer to this question is  affirmative  but I am unable to rigorously justify  my intuition  .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, {\cal A}, {\Bbb P})$ be the probability space.  Since $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence of random variables, $\{X_n > a\} \in {\cal A}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ and $a \in \Bbb R$.

$$\{\sup_n X_n > a\} = \bigcup_n \{ X_n > a \} \in {\cal A} $$
$$\{\limsup_n X_n > a\} = \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k\ge n}\{ X_k > a \} \in {\cal A} $$

Hence $\limsup_n X_n$ is a random variable.  <del>It has *nothing* to do with boundedness.</del>

Comment: (+1)I am unable to understand the notation $\{\sup_n X_n \ge a\}$  . Also , isn't boundedness necessary for the supremum to exist ?

Comment: A random variable is a real valued measurable function. So the correct statement is: $sup_n X_n$ is a random variable if the sequence is bounded above at each sample point.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , is it possible that a bounded random variable becomes unbounded at a sample point ? Also , I am unable to understand the set theoretic notation used in this proof . Can you please explain it  to me more carefully .

Comment: @John What is relevant here is boundedness (above) of the sequence of numbers $(X_1(\omega),X_1(\omega),...)$ for each $\omega$. When you say $X_n$'s are bounded random variables what you are saying is $sup_{\omega} X_n(\omega) <\infty$ for each fixed $n$. This hypothesis is of no use in proving measurability.

Comment: @John Sorry for the mistake $\{\sup_n X_n \ge a\}$.  I reminded that $\sup_n (-1/n) \ge 0$ but $-1/n < 0$ for all $n$, so it should be strict inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much !But I am unable to understand the meaning of this notation . Can you please explain it  , or give a reference that uses the above notation . Please edit your answer to include explanation for the set theoretic notation that you have used .

Comment: $\{X \ge a\}$ is a shorthand for $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \ge a\}$, so ...